# Using power series to create a bound

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have a question from the following computation of a real integral using a complex integral. The problem writes

$$\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}=\frac{iz}{z^2}+\frac{(iz)^2}{2!z^2}+\frac{(iz)^3}{3!z^3}+\dots$$

Why is it that the remainder term after the $\frac{iz}{z^2}$ is bounded? as $\epsilon \to 0$? This isn't apparent to me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first displayed expansion is incorrect, double check it. The terms should have negative signs in front of them and the last shown term should be divided by $z^2$ and not $z^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by the power series of the exponential function,
$$
\frac{{1 - e^{iz} }}{{z^2 }} =  - \frac{1}{{z^2 }}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{(iz)^n }}{{n!}}}  =  - \frac{i}{z} + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {i^n \frac{{z^n }}{{(n + 2)!}}} 
$$
for all complex $z \neq 0$. Thus if $|z|\leq c$ with some $c>0$, then
$$
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {i^n \frac{{z^n }}{{(n + 2)!}}} } \right| \le \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\left| z \right|^n }}{{(n + 2)!}}}  \le \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{c^n }}{{(n + 2)!}}}  \le \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{c^n }}{{n!}}}  = e^c .
$$

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out
\begin{align*}
E(z)
&=\frac{(iz)^2}{2!z^2}+\frac{(iz)^3}{3!z^2}+\frac{(iz)^4}{4!z^2}+\cdots\\
&=\frac{i^2}{2!}+z\frac{i^3}{3!}+z^2\frac{i^4}{4!}+\cdots\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k\ge2}z^{k-2}\frac{i^k}{k!}
\end{align*}
the second term of this last expression is a convergent series, whose summands goes to $0$ as $z\to 0$.